# component supposed to listen to emitted events from child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2

I've starting exercising `vuejs` and I've learned that to communicate data from child component back to parent component we use `this.$root.$emit('name-of-event', myobject);`

which would be received from parent with the help of `this.$root.$on('name-of-event');`

In the other hand, I got a vuejs project which I use to compare what I had learned with what is implemented in it and there I found that the component listening to my event is not the parent of that component (the tag of the component triggering the event is not rendered in the one who is listening to it)

My question: is it always the case that the direct parent is the one who listens to the triggered event ? could other component be listening to emitted events ?

**myAcomponent.vue :**

```
    updateDate(value) {

 //body of updateDate method
            this.$root.$emit('date-updated', this.project);
          
    }
```

**myBcomponent.vue :**

```
<script>
      created() {
        this.$root.$on('date-updated', project => {
          this.updateproject(project);
        });
     }
</script>

<template>
//no call in template for myAcomponent
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Is it always the case that the direct parent is the one who listens to the triggered event ?*** - Answer is Partially Yes, There are two scenarios or use cases **:**

1. If you are working on a large application and there is a need to share data between multiple components and these components don't have any relation with each other, then you have to use a state management solution. You can use [`Pinia`](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) - which is the state management library recommended by the Vue core team.
2. If you want to share the data only between the siblings under single parent, In that case you can give a try to this solution.

   - Pass data from one child to parent component using event emitter.
   - Capture the event in parent and then pass back to another child by using props.

Comment: can we say that all the components of an application are siblings except the component that calls another inside is the parent (<my-child>) and the called component is the child ? Or is there a hierarchy to differentiate them?

Comment: @bohitbti Siblings components are like `parent -> child1 and child2`. Here both child1 and child2 are siblings as both having a single parent. but if `parent1 -> child3` and `parent2 -> child4`. here, child3 and child4 are not siblings these are independent components.

Comment: **1)** I checked on my project and I found that `myAcomponent.vue` & `myBcomponent.vue` **aren't siblings yet they are independent components + every component belongs to different vue app** (executed on diferent main.js) in this case can you insight me how could **how would events be exchanged between them ?**

Comment: **2)** to know if parent1 is the parent of child3 I must find in `parent.vue` this tag `<child3 />` **or  it's not always the trick to catch them ?**

Comment: @bohitbti Regarding 1) you have to use pinia for the state management. So that you can easily set and get the data across the application in independent components.

Comment: in my project I didn't trace any use of pinia, I still don't understand how this exchange has been done but I accept your answer as you warned me about some stuff

Answer (score 0):

there is a better way to improve the event emit

lets say you have component A and B you want to transfer data from A to B also they don't have direct relationship

1.create JavaScript file and add the below code on JavaScript file save it FIleName.js

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
    export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

2 on component A.vue emit the event on methods or on api call

```
import {EventBus} from "path/FIleName.js";



 update(data){

    EventBus.$emit("event-name",Data);
     }
```

3 the last thing you want to do is listen on a component B.vue which you want to get the data or the event and fire a function to do something with the data you passed

```
import {EventBus} from "@/service/EventBus.js";
 created() {
    EventBus.$on("gallery-created",(Data) =>{
      this.MyFunction(Data);
    })
  },
```

**By doing this you can pass an event and data to any component using event bus method.**